# PHP Array to String equivalent

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm wondering if anyone has a recursive solution to converting an array to a string.

Here's what I mean:

An array `$args` that has the following contents:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $hello
    [1] => 411px
    [Jeeves] => Array
        (
            [compiling] => 1
        )

)
```

---

Result after calling `arr_to_string($args)`:

```
array($hello,"411px", "Jeeves" => array("compiling" => 1));
```

Note:
It recognizes the $ sign in front and therefore does not add quotes. It does the same for numbers.

Anyone have any solution or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: Playing with the code and make a data of it is always dangerous game. Programmer should avoid such cases. Most of time it is much better to treat data as data, in the XML format, for example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you are after

- [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

That won't give you $hello though, because $hello cannot be in an array. It's always just the value of the variable, not the variable name. If you want '$hello', put it into single quotes when inserting it to the array, e.g. insert it as a string, not as a variable.

Comment: Wow. PHP never ceases to amaze me. It's got a function for EVERYTHING. Thanks man for uncovering this gem.

Comment: Oh and about the $ sign. I'm looking to evaluate it later (when the variable is known) - that's why it shouldn't have single quotes around it.

Comment: If you want a more compact representation of the arrays contents, try encoding as JSON with json_encode() or try serialize() for a format that is most reusable by PHP.

Comment: @Matt that's impossible. If you do `$myArray[] = $foo`, then the array will contain the *value* of `$foo`, not the name you gave to the variable. Put in the name 'hello' and later evaluate it as variable variable. See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @Matt why not to set this element *after* you've got it's value, not before? And what is the final goal of these unusual movements?