# Dropdown in Yii cGrid - 2 variables

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, cgridview

I have $model1, $model2 and OwnerID populated in my controller and it renders the data in my zii.widgets.grid.CGridView Problem comes in when I want to send $model2 to the view as well like so:

```
$this->render('listView', array('model1'=>$model, 'model2' => $model2, 'OwnerID' => 14));
```

and in the view I have:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'listKeys',
    'dataProvider'=>$model1->search($OwnerID),
    'summaryText'=>'Showing {start} to {end} of {count} keys.',
    'columns'=>array(
        array('value'=>'$data["id"]', 'header'=>'Key ID'),
        array(
            'type'=>'raw',
            'header'=>'Edit',
            'value'=>'CHtml::dropDownList("partyList","owner_party_id", $model2)'
        ),
    ),
));
```

I get "**Undefined variable: model2**" There is data in $model2, if I comment out the dropDown in the grid and have the dropdown list outside the grid like so:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("partyList","owner_party_id", $model2) ?>
```

then everything works fine. How can I add the dropDownList in CGridView? $model1 is a list of file and $model2 is a list of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$model2` needs to be a string or a variable recognized by `CGridView`.

To get a string representation of the array use [`var_export()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605783/428543)

```
...
'value'=>'CHtml::dropDownList("partyList","owner_party_id",'.var_export($model2).')',
...
```

To make `$model2` a `CGridView` variable you'd need to extend `CGridView` as explained [in this Yii wiki page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/)

Comment: Sweet, thanks "topher" I could not get var_export to work(tried implode as well?) but the link to extend CGridView was pretty simple and worked.